# knockout computed function

Tags: html, knockout.js

I am using knockout.js.

**Here's my scenario:**

I have an input field and three checkboxes.  Each checkbox has an associated value with it. For instance, checkbox1(500), checkbox2(200), checkbox3(100). When a user clicks on the checkbox, I want the vallue for that checkbox to appear on the input field. If a user clicks on two checkboxes, I want the sum of the values of the two checkboxes to appear on the input field. Same thing applies when all three checkboxes are checked.

**My take on the problem**

I figured that I need a computed function that will compute values based on the checkboxes that are checked. Then, I can bind the computed function to my input field.

In my viewmodel, I have this computed function:

```
var classes = ko.computed(function() { 
    var total = 0; 
    if(primaryClass.checked)
    total+= parseInt(primSalary()); 

    if(secondaryClass.checked)
    total+= parseInt(secSalary());    

    if(otherClass.checked)    
    total+= parseInt(otherSalary());

    return total;    
 });
```

In my view, I bind my values like this:

```
<input type="text" class="input-medium" placeholder="0" data-bind="text: classes"/>
```

**However, when I do that, the console throws this message:**

"Unable to parse bindings.↵Message: ReferenceError: classes is not defined;↵Bindings value: value: classes"

I would appreciate your help folks.

Comment: Can you put the rest of your view model code? I'd guess that the classes property isn't publicly visible. Also, what are primaryClass, secondaryClass and otherClass in your computed?

Comment: @PaulManzotti, those are observables defiend in my viewmodel and tied to my checkboxes like this: <input data-bind="checked: primaryInsurance" type="checkbox" value="500">500</input>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to say what is wrong without seeing all code but it seems to me that you don't add `classes computed` to the view model or don't call `applyBindings`.
Also it is better to achieve such behavior in another way. You can bind checked binding to `observableArray`, in that case your computed will look nicer:

```
<input data-bind="checked: selectedValues" type="checkbox" value="500">500</input>
<input data-bind="checked: selectedValues" type="checkbox" value="200">200</input>
<input data-bind="checked: selectedValues" type="checkbox" value="100">100</input>

<br/>
Result:
<input data-bind="value: sum" type="text"></input>

function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.selectedValues = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.sum = ko.computed(function () {
            var total = 0;
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.selectedValues(), function (item) {
                total += parseInt(item);
            });
            return total;
        });

    }

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Here is working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/uFQdq/

Comment: I very much appreciate your answer. I have a question, is my syntax (primaryInsurance.checked) correct? I try looking online for this but couldnt find an answer.

Comment: I am not sure. Is primaryInsurance object with checked property? Could you share your view model and html?

Comment: I figurd the reference null problem. It was about context. I had to use $root.classes. my issue now is that when I click on the checkbox, I am getting NaN. Anyone know why?  Here's my fiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/uFQdq/4/

Comment: Since my original problem was solved, for this new problem that I have, if you would like to answer, then please visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15576008/input-field-displaying-nan

Answer (score 2):

You need to have the `classes` function assigned to the ViewModel:

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.classes = ko.computed(function () {
        // your function
    });
}
```