# input field displaying NaN

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

**Description**

Hi, I am using knock out. I have three checkboxes and an input field. When I click on checkbox, the value of the checkbox should appear on the input field. However, instead of getting the value of the checkbox, I see NaN.

**[jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/uFQdq/4)**

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;  
    self.primaryClass = ko.observable("50"); 
    self.secondaryClass = ko.observable("40"); 
    self.otherClass = ko.observable("10"); 

    self.selectedValues = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.sum = ko.computed(function () {
        var total = 0;
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.selectedValues(), function (item) {
            total += parseInt(item);
        });
        return total;
    });

}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/uFQdq/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out:

http://jsfiddle.net/Dtwigs/uFQdq/5/

Do your inputs like this to make them dynamic:

```
<label>
<input data-bind="checked: selectedValues, value: primaryClass" type="checkbox"></input>
<span data-bind="text: primaryClass"></span>
</label>
```

Change your values to the values in text.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the code, on this line,

```
total += parseInt(item);
```

the variable item is the value of your checkboxes.

```
<input data-bind="checked: selectedValues" type="checkbox" value="primaryClass">500</input>
<input data-bind="checked: selectedValues" type="checkbox" value="secondaryClass">200</input>
<input data-bind="checked: selectedValues" type="checkbox" value="otherClass">100</input>
```

meaning you are trying to `parseInt("primaryClass")` ... and so on.

Try changing the value of the checkbox to numbers.

Like here: http://jsfiddle.net/2L4W9/

Comment: Spot on, you were adding strings together, hence NaN. I think you want those "values" to be `class="primaryClass"` etc

Comment: I cannot add static values in my checkboxes. Those values will change. That's why I have observables. So, am I setting the observable incorrectly?

Comment: That might have to be another question. @Stranger. Sorry, I am not that familiar with knockoutjs

Comment: This is actually what I was asking from the beginning. If I start another question, we gonna have redundancy. Its ok if you are not familiar. Same here by the way. Thanks for your help